# Problems with rendering a templated asp.net mvc telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a problem with rendering a mvc telerik template  grid control. Every thing seems fine but I have this error:

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 14:
>    Line 15:
>    Line 16:
>   }).Width(100); Line 17:                              columns.Bound(p
>   => p.ProductName).Title("Product"); Line 18:                              columns.Bound(p => p.WholesalePrice).Title("Price");

here is my source code:

```
@(
        Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .DataKeys(key => key.Add(p => p.ID))
        .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                         columns.Template(p =>
                                              {
                                                  @<div> 
                                                       <img alt="@p.ProductName"src="@p.ImageURL" />
                                                   </div>
                                              }).Width(100);
                         columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product");
                         columns.Bound(p => p.WholesalePrice).Title("Price");
                     })
        .Pageable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
)
```

without defining the column template everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@(
    Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).Name("grid")
        .Columns( columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Template(
                              @<text> bla bla </text>
                          );
                          columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product");
                      }).Pageable().Sortable()
)
```

Comment: thanks, this works. however I need to display a grid with images. do you know what wrong with the code that i've edited